# CPU is very spikey and erratic, network latency. Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance, cpu-usage

Something is making my server go crazy. First it was just the network had some bad latency, then I noticed it was on the server, not the network.
I thought it to be HDD related but I am not sure.
It seems to spike every few seconds for less than a second.
I shutdown Hmail and Apache, neither were the issue.

A link to 2 images, one of the CPU graph and one of the Process list sorted by CPU time. Also in there are a couple text files with Ping from anotehr machine and  a netstat -a -b .
http://www.rscivil.com/dell/

[image]
[image]

```
Reply from 10.0.0.5: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.5: bytes=32 time=2898ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.5: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.5: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.5: bytes=32 time=2026ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.5: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.5: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.5: bytes=32 time=2022ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.5: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
```

Win Server 2003 SP2
Dell PowerEdge sc1425
Xeon 3.4GHZ  (Dual Core)
2GB Ram
RAID 1 (mirror )with 2x 1TB Hard Drives

Used mainly as a file server and Active directory and DNS server.
Also runs Apache (very light load) and HMailServer for email.

It rarely has load issues. 
The RAID controller shows the raid (and each drive) as Optimal.

Any Suggestions where to go from here?

Solution:
I have 4 external drive bays hooked up to a pci-x raid controller.
One of these bays took a crap and was generating a ton of interrupts.
Turned it off and voila.
I found out it was the interrupts by using process explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a swing at it with process explorer:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

See if you can see a process spiking periodically. Are you pinging the host from the same network, or from remote (like over a vpn?).

Comment: I have been looking for that tool, Thank you very much for pointing me to it! =)

Comment: Oops. Hit enter prematurely. Ok so it is interrupts going crazy. Bad processor? Anyone have an idea of what could cause this?
http://www.rscivil.com/dell/process_explorer.PNG

Comment: Possible causes are driver issues (when DPCs just take too much time) or excessive numbers of interrupts due to some defective or badly designed hardware (mostly expansion cards) - maybe even the NIC. What are the numbers for "context switch delta", "interrupt delta" and "DPC delta" in the CPU statistics of the system information window (call it up through the menu View -> System Information)?

Comment: Context Switch Delta: 3466

Comment: Context Switch Delta: 1540-3466
Interrupt Delta: 500 - 1150
DPC Delta: 58-308

Comment: Page Fault Delta 1100 - 7400

Comment: Oh, I forgot. the PING was on the local network, and is just the first way I knew my server was going crazy.

Comment: I have 4 external drive bays hooked up to a pci-x raid controller.
One of these bays took a crap and was generating a ton of interrupts.
Turned it off and voila.